# nativescript-vue cannot read data property in lifecycle hooks

Tags: vue-component, nativescript-vue, lifecycle-hook

im reading nfc tags through my created hook and I would like to pass them to my data properties.
It shows me that I cannot read or set the property 'currentArticle'. I tried suggestions like

> let self = this
>
> > self.currentArticle

but it did not work. Some people say you should have access to data variables like:

> this.currentArticle

That way doesn't work as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it through declaring let self = this **at the beginning** of the created hook.
Then I simply used the self.currentArticle as I already talked about the suggestions I have seen about this problem.

Comment: I have to wait one day until I can accept my own answer as solved.